# Qt, memory increase with mtrace

Tags: c++, qt4, valgrind, mtrace

we have a multi-thread c++ qt (4.8.1) application on an embedded arm linux platform with many qgraphicsitem descendants. When calling their update() method, mtrace shows incremental memory usage, some 16-18 bytes on each update. Watching the applications VSZ (with ps, or top commands), it is also incrementing constantly. If we start the application within valgrind --tool=memcheck, and the application terminates normally, we don't see "definitely lost" blocks.

If we comment out the update() calls, mtrace does not show any more unfreed areas.

Is it possible that there are "still reachable" and constantly growing memory blocks, reallocated areas, STL vectors, etc., within Qt? If yes, how can we clear them periodically?

The program structure is as follows:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  // new thread creations, initializations, qt object creations
  ...
  mtrace();
  while ( runEnabled ) {
    // this is where new events arrive, and the graphics is updated
    ...
  }
  muntrace();

  // cleanups, desctructions
  ...
}
```

So mtrace monitors only the active part, which should run for months in our embedded environment.

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: What are you doing in this `update` function? Are you creating or allocating anything that you then forget to destroy or unallocate?

Comment: void update(const QRectF &rect = QRectF()) is within class  QGraphicsItem and is not overloaded. Our overloaded paint() methods are called in the background but there are no dynamic allocations within our paint() methods.